# Loading multiple .mat files containing the same variable name and changing the variable names simultaneously?

Tags: matlab, file, mat

So I have a directory that has many .mat files:

apples.mat, oranges.mat, bananas.mat, grapes.mat, apricots.mat, pears.mat, pineapple.mat

All of these .mat files has a variable name "calories" assigned a value. How do I load all of these .mat files simultaneously in MATLAB and change the variables for each one from calories to calories_(fruit name) so that I can have all the variable values in the workspace to play with?

For example, I want to load apples.mat and change its variable name from calories to calories_apple, then load oranges.mat and change is variable name from calories_orange, etc. without doing it all manually.

I know it's something along the lines of creating a string with the different fruit names, and the indexing along the string to load a file and change its variable from variable to variable_%s with the %s indicating the fruit content generated along the loop. It's a big mess for me, however, I don't think I'm structuring it right. Would anyone care to help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would load each `.mat` file in sequence and put each of the corresponding calories as a separate field being all combined into a single `struct` for you to access.  Given the directory of where these `.mat` files appear, do something like this:

```
%// Declare empty structure
s = struct()
folder = '...'; %// Place directory here

%// Get all MAT files in directory
f = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.mat'));

%// For each MAT file...
for idx = 1 : numel(f)

    %// Get absolute path to MAT file - i.e. folder/file.mat
    name = fullfile(folder, f(idx).name);

    %// Load this MAT file into the workspace and get the calories variable
    load(name, 'calories');

    %// Get the name of the fruit, are all of the characters except the last 4 (i.e. .mat)
    fruit_name = f(idx).name(1:end-4);

    %// Place corresponding calories of the fruit in the structure
    s.(['calories_' fruit_name]) = calories;
end
```

You can then access each of the calories like so using dot notation:

```
c = s.calories_apple;
d = s.calories_orange;

...
...
```

... and so on.

Comment: Yay structures and dynamic field referencing for the win! +1

Comment: @Benoit_11 - Merci mon ami :) Ça me fait grand plaisir pour lire tes réponses dans le puissance des images.  Incroyable!

Comment: Oh merci du compliment! Pareillement pour toi :)

Comment: I have a problem with the name being too long and thus truncating.

Comment: @Rand - How "long" are these names?

Comment: Well the directory is under c:\User\myname\Desktop\folder\subfolder, and I noticed that when I put the folder name under "folder", I get "fruit_name" as "c:\User\myname\Desktop\folder\subfolder\fruit_name" which is very long.

Comment: @Rand - Ah $h!t.  Sorry, let me fix it.

Comment: @Rand - Done. Try it now.  I mistakenly added in the full path as the name... you just need the fruit!

Comment: @Rand - No problem at all.  It was my pleasure.  Thanks for spotting my mistake and good luck!

Comment: @Benoit_11 - Je viens de créer un chat room pour MATLAB donc nous pouvons discutons n'importe quoi en MATLAB :P Visitez-le quand tu es libre! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab

Comment: Bonne idée @rayryeng! Merci de l'invitation je vais aller faire un tour :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you do not mean to include the parenthesis in `calories_(fruit name)`. I am also assuming there are no other `.mat` files in your current directory. This should do the trick:

```
theFiles = dir('*.mat');
for k = 1:length(theFiles)
    load(theFiles(k).name, 'calories');
    eval(['calories_' theFiles(k).name(1:length(theFiles(k).name)-4) ' =  calories;'])
    clear calories
end
```

Let me know if this helps or not.

**EDIT**
As, rayryeng points out. The use of eval is, apparently, a bad practice. So, if you are willing to change the way you are thinking about the problem, I suggest you use a structure. In which case, rayryeng's response would be an acceptable answer, even though it does not directly answers your original question.

Comment: FYI, the use of `eval` is considered bad practice.  I won't downvote, but there is a strong following here on StackOverflow in the MATLAB tag where this practice is discouraged.  You may receive downvotes from those people.  See this informative post by Loren Shure on why you shouldn't use `eval` here: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/01/04/more-in-eval/

Comment: Sorry I should have linked here: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/ - BTW, I appreciate the edit.