# How to load mat file into a matrix in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I am doing one MATLAB program(image processing). I have stored almost 100 '.mat' files in one folder named 'out' in D drive (D:\MATLAB-examples\camera_10\out). All the mat files have the name starting with 'v_1_....'   . I want to load all these mat files from 'out' folder into single a 2D matrix named 'v' to process it further. Can anyone give me a solution????

Comment: Try to adapt [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31035962/2732801) to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
 indir='D:\MATLAB-examples\camera_10\out';
 cd(indir)

indirf=[indir,'v_1*.mat'] %look only for .mat files
files = dir(indirf);

for k=1:length(files)

    fname=files(k).name; %filename

    f=fullfile(indir,fname); %filename+path
    load(f,'-mat')
%do your stuff here

end
```

Comment: use `fullfile` to concatenate file path. this way you avoid duplicate or forgotten file separators (which happened in this case) `indirf=fullfile(indir,'v_1*.mat')`

Comment: when i run the above code i am getting the output as:-"indirf =

D:\MATLAB-examples\camera_10\outv_1*.mat" how can i see that single matrix containing all the mat files.

Comment: i'm not sure to get your question. But files is a struct, in particular you can look to files.names in order to see the filenames